# Yosemite, how to reset/reinstall network?

Tags: network, wifi, dns

For some reasons every time I connect to an insecure WiFi, Yosemite cannot route to the DNS servers of that WiFi. The DNS servers are correctly set, just cannot reach them.

And after installing uninstalling a few softs over the years, have a bunch of network interfaces, not sure they're all relevant

```
lo0:     flags=8049<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 16384
gif0:    flags=8010<POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST> mtu 1280
stf0:    flags=0<> mtu 1280
en0:     flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
en1:     flags=8963<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
bridge0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
p2p0:    flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 2304
awdl0:   flags=8943<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1452
```

Well, tried to remove all `/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/*` and reboot, the problem persists. Not sure what to do next (besides going to Linux)

Comment: all those profiles are in your Network settings, so what is holding you back in removing them? Do you use custom DNS ?

Comment: No custom DNS - these profiles can be removed **where**?

Comment: check which DNS is been used with "ipconfig getoption en0 domain_name_server" and try adding Google DNS server. 8.8.8.8

Comment: The DNS server is correct (works on my Linux and is identical). I tried adding the google servers, but the problem is the Net cannot route to that DNS server - whichever it is. Checked the routing tables, and the Default goes to that wifi server - seems ok. There must be a problem in the routing somewhere. This is why I'd like to erase / reset all of that! Thanks for helping anyway.

Comment: Did you run the traceroute yourdomin.com

Comment: `root@MacBook-Air:~# traceroute  11.12.101.15` gives `traceroute: findsaddr: write: No such process`